# Is it possible to know how long a nuclear reactor has been running in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

If I'm not mistaken, recommissioning a power plant is the way to avoid nuclear accidents.
Per some descriptions I saw around, I should do that every 10 to 20 turns.

So, is there a way to know for how long a Nuclear Power Plant has been running?
It would be impossible to pen+paper to track that kind of information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes, it is.

When you move your mouse over the "Recommission Nuclear Reactor" option, you'll see a tooltip, where the "Reactor Age" in turns can be seen.

Note that recommissioning a Nuclear Reactor will reset its age to 0.

[image: "Recommission Nuclear Reactor" tooltip screenshot]

In this case, the reactor's been running for 84 turns since it's been built or recommissioned.

Comment: Wow, 84 turns... that's got to be double what I've ever seen!  I assume it leaked?

Comment: Thank you! I really needed that information!

Comment: @Joe, yes, it's been leaking a lot. It originally belonged to the AI and had already started leaking while we were at war. By the time I had conquered the city, the Nuclear Reactor was already over 50 rounds old. I've been trying to recommission it, but I can't start the project until the area is decontaminated, and it keeps leaking before decontamination is over...

Comment: I'm just impressed you've made it that long post-nuclear age... but then again I've never seen "Train Astronauts" because I've never played long enough with the entire world at the Information Age to get the competition!  Either I'm winning (and am far ahead of most of the world) by the time you can build nuclear reactors, or I'm losing badly (and, well, lose) by this point... (Or is this a "Just one more turn..." game?)

Comment: @Joe, yeah, definitely a "One more turn" thing. I always disable the turn limit and score victory in a game. I also usually disable cultural victory, because with the other victory types I can just stop to avoid winning, but not with cultural victory.